# How to Install Gitlab on Centos 6.6 VPS?

Tags: linux, centos, gitlab

I tried installing as mentioned here: https://about.gitlab.com/downloads/

```
sudo yum install openssh-server
sudo yum install postfix
sudo yum install cronie
sudo service postfix start
sudo chkconfig postfix on
sudo lokkit -s http -s ssh

curl -O https://downloads-packages.s3.amazonaws.com/centos-6.6/gitlab-7.7.2_omnibus.5.4.2.ci-1.el6.x86_64.rpm
sudo rpm -i gitlab-7.7.2_omnibus.5.4.2.ci-1.el6.x86_64.rpm
sudo gitlab-ctl reconfigure
```

It looks like everything went successfully, but but I don't get anything on my hostname. Is there anything I missed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

GitLab will try to setup the FQDN by using the hostname of your machine. To do this manually, open `/etc/gitlab/gitlab.rb` and edit the external url according to the [documentation](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/omnibus-gitlab/blob/7-7-stable/README.md#configuring-the-external-url-for-gitlab), which by the way if you haven't already read, I suggest that you do it!

Comment: Finally i used digitalocean one click installer, it is cheaper and less headache. Can't try your solution now, but I guess it is right.